# Capybara within is extremly slow when updated from to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I have such method:

```
def self.click_button(label)
  selector = "menu.toolbar"
  page.within(selector) do
    page.click_link(label)
  end
end
```

On capybara `1.1.2` (ancient) it works fine, in modern version `2.5.0`, it is very slow - takes like 10 minutes to return empty element.

When I pause with debugger just before `within` I can find element without any issues with jquery on js console. I am using chrome to run tests.

Best,
Slawosz

Answer (score 3):

Capybara 2.5.0 is also ancient, being that it was released August 26, 2015.  I would recommend upgrading to the latest release (2.12.1 as of now).

`within` will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for a matching visible element to be found, and if not found will then raise an exception.  If you're saying it takes 10 minutes to do that then you need to reduce whatever you have set `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to.

Comment: Apparently it looks like someone did some crazy hack 5 years ago and there was infinite loop with sleep every 0.5 second.............